# My application outputs DBNull but in the database it isn't DBNull

Tags: mysql, vb.net

My application outputs "System.InvalidCastException: "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."

```
Dim sqlquery = String.Format("SELECT id, date, film, start_time, end_time, participants_count, confirmed FROM calendar WHERE id='" & id & "'")
    connection.Open()
    With command
        .Connection = connection
        .CommandText = sqlquery
    End With
    dataadapter.SelectCommand = command
    dataadapter.Fill(datatable)
    id = Convert.ToInt32(datatable.Rows(0).Item("id"))
    Dim date_ As String = datatable.Rows(0).Item("date").ToString
    Dim film As String = datatable.Rows(0).Item("film").ToString
    Dim start_time As String = datatable.Rows(0).Item("start_time").ToString
    Dim end_time As String = datatable.Rows(0).Item("end_time").ToString
    Dim participants_count As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(datatable.Rows(0).Item("participants_count"))
    Dim confirmed As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(datatable.Rows(0).Item("confirmed"))
```

The problem arises there: "participants_count" and "confirmed". All the other columns are working perfectly. In the database these two columns aren't DBNull: [Picture of the real MySQL-Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dJB5.jpg). They can't even be DBNull: [MySQL Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzmjp.jpg)

If I output the value of both with a MessageBox it also contains nothing.
I would be very grateful if I became a solution.

Julius

Comment: What happens if you put .ToString on the end of those two like you did the others?

Comment: @CharlesMay Unfortunately this doesn't work either. I get a string, but it's just empty...

Comment: And you're sure there is a value in date and film, etc...? because .ToString could handle the dbnull if no record is there. I don't think you're getting any data from the query.

Comment: Have you tested `datatable.Rows.Count > 0`? If the ID is an `int`, don't add quotes in the SQL.

Comment: Gah, the sql injection hole, it burns us!

Comment: `date` is a [keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) so you should quote it like `\`date\``. It's simpler to just quote all column names really.

Comment: I get data for the others and for those two just DBNull (I output the other strings)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, but I get at least some data. I changed it, but it hasn't fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim participants_count As Integer
Integer.TryParse(datatable.Rows(0).Item("participants_count").Tostring, participants_count)
```

This will attempt to convert it to an Integer and returns 0 if it fails otherwise it will set the value to participants_count.  This should help with the DBNull issue.  You can do this with the confirmed field to.

Comment: But I need tha value for those two. In the MySql-Database it also isn't DBNull...

Comment: This will set the variables to the value if it's successful.  If it fails it will set the variable to 0.  You can also use the TryParse in an If statement.  Check out this link https://www.dotnetperls.com/parse-vbnet

Answer (score 0):

You can get the query results without using a DataTable. That way you can be exact about the data types and so there is less chance of something unexpected happening:

```
Dim connStr = "your connection string"
Dim sql = "SELECT `id`, `date`, `film`, `start_time`, `end_time`, `participants_count`, `confirmed` FROM `calendar` WHERE `id` = @id"

Dim id = "2"

Dim date_ As DateTime
Dim start_time As TimeSpan
Dim end_time As TimeSpan
Dim participants_count As Integer
Dim confirmed As Boolean

Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter With {
                           .ParameterName = "@id",
                           .MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar,
                           .Size = 8,
                           .Value = id})

        conn.Open()
        Dim rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If rdr.HasRows Then
            date_ = rdr.GetDateTime(1)
            start_time = rdr.GetTimeSpan(3)
            end_time = rdr.GetTimeSpan(4)
            participants_count = rdr.GetInt16(5)
            confirmed = rdr.GetBoolean(6)
        End If

        conn.Close()

    End Using
End Using
```

The SQL parameter should have its `.MySqlDbType` and `.Size` set to match the `id` column in the database. The `rdr.Get...` functions should be chosen to match the types from the database.